# Table doesn't show all data when i filter by a string

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, jtable, resultset

I would like to obtain a messageDialog if the id which I'm filtering is not in the table model I created. The problem is that the code works fine without the `if`, however when I add the `if` for the messageDialog condition, I realize that the data is found but not shown.

Compare:
[image: Compare]

Code:

```
public void buscarNumeroSerie (String nserie)

{
 try {

             String [] campos={"NUMERO_SERIE","MARCA","GAVETA"};
             String filtroNS = nserie;
             String NSSQL = "SELECT NUMERO_SERIE,MARCA,GAVETA FROM"
                     + "(SELECT NUMERO_SERIE,MARCA,GAVETA FROM discos_wd "
                     + "UNION "
                     + "SELECT NUMERO_SERIE,MARCA,GAVETA FROM discos_toshiba "
                     + "UNION "
                     + "SELECT NUMERO_SERIE,MARCA,GAVETA FROM discos_seagate "
                     + "UNION "
                     + "SELECT NUMERO_SERIE,MARCA,GAVETA FROM discos_samsung "
                     + "UNION "
                     + "SELECT NUMERO_SERIE,MARCA,GAVETA FROM discos_hitachi )"
                     + "AS TROUBLE WHERE NUMERO_SERIE LIKE '%"+filtroNS+"%'";

            System.out.println(NSSQL); 
                    nsconn = metodosPool.dataSource.getConnection();
                    ModeloTablaLista = new DefaultTableModel(null, campos);
                    stmnt = nsconn.prepareStatement(NSSQL);
                    ResultSet nsrs = stmnt.executeQuery(NSSQL);

            if(nsrs.next()== true){
                    String [] nsfila = new String[3];


                while (nsrs.next())
                    {
                        nsfila[0]=nsrs.getString("Numero_Serie");
                        nsfila[1]=nsrs.getString("Marca");
                        nsfila[2]=nsrs.getString("Gaveta");
                        ModeloTablaLista.addRow(nsfila);
                    }

                        nsrs.close();
                        stmnt.close();
                        tablaDiscosGaveta.setModel(ModeloTablaLista);
           }

           else
              {

                System.err.println("No existen datos asociados");
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Disco no encontrado, quiere:");
               }
```

My idea is that the left image, that which contains the `if` bit of code, shows the results I need just like the image on the right. I've tried with `for` loops, adding a new resultSet and changing the position of the `if` condition without results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nsrs.next()` moves to the next record in the `ResultSet`, so

```
if(nsrs.next()== true){
                String [] nsfila = new String[3];
```

moves to the first record.

Then

```
while (nsrs.next()) {
```

moves to the second record, and the first record is skipped. So the code needs to process the record before moving to the next record.  Here's a different approach:

```
//if(nsrs.next()== true){
//                String [] nsfila = new String[3];

String [] nsfila = null;

while (nsrs.next()) {
    nsfila = new String[3];
    nsfila[0]=nsrs.getString("Numero_Serie");
    nsfila[1]=nsrs.getString("Marca");
    nsfila[2]=nsrs.getString("Gaveta");
    ModeloTablaLista.addRow(nsfila);
}

if (nsfila == null) {
  // no data...
}
```

See also: try with resources, or `close()` in a finally block.

Comment: Thanks! this was the solution i needed :)